# TypeScript package creation declaration files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm creating a package in typescript and I generate the declaration files using the tsc tool but when I try to import this package from another project type definitions doesn't load automatically and I get type errors. How can I achieve this problem? I know there are modules that you don't need to install or specify typings to use but I couldn't find how to do this.

EDIT - details: I generate declaration file using the `tsc --declarations` command and all of them goes directly to the build directory with js files. I've `{"types": "./build/index.d.ts", "typescript.tsdk": "./build"}` in my package.json but it doesn't seem to effect anything. Here are some examples:

build/index.d.ts

```
import Network from './network';
import Queue from './queue';
export { Queue, Network, Jobs };
```

build/network/index.d.ts

```
import Address from './address';
import Socket from './socket';
import Packet from './packet';
export { Address, Socket, Packet };
declare var _default: {
    Address: typeof Address;
    Socket: typeof Socket;
    Packet: typeof Packet;
};
export default _default;
```

build/network/packet.dt.ts

```
export default class Packet {
    private params;
    static fromString(str: string): Packet;
    toString(): string;
}
```

Comment: please add details, how your d.ts file look, where you put it, how you reference it

Comment: Alright, I've edited my question and added some examples of declaration files.

Comment: ok, how do you reference them? what errors do you get?

Comment: I don't get particularly one error, basically my classes, interfaces etc. don't get defined. So for example I've a class that extends `Socket` and when I try to use `this.connect` in it, I get `this.connect is not defined` error.

Comment: do you get the error during compilation or runtime?

Comment: Yes, `src/worker.ts(20,17): error TS2339: Property 'connect' does not exist on type 'Worker'.`

Comment: so do you extend this Worker class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136031/discussion-between-brahim-duran-and-maximus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use default export and your package is inside `node_modules`, you can import it the following way:

```
import Socket from "core/build/network/socket";

class Abc extends Socket {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.connect('address');
    }
}

let s = new Socket();
s.connect('address');
```